angular 18 - @let syntax in templates
The Angular team just implemented the new @let syntax in templates. According to this comment it's implemented in this commit, which should already be released in version 18.0.2




I updated my NX workspace to use @angular/compiler 18.0.2 (npm update)

However it's still not working. I'm still getting the following error:
X [ERROR] NG5002: Incomplete block "let showSpan". If you meant to write the @ character, you should use the "&#64;" HTML entity instead. [plugin angular-compiler]

    libs/example-ng-bootstrap/calendar/src/calendar.component.html:32:16:
      32 │                 @let showSpan = (day !== null) && day.isInMonth;
         ╵                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  Error occurs in the template of component BsCalendarComponent.

    libs/example-ng-bootstrap/calendar/src/calendar.component.ts:14:15:
      14 │   templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So what am I doing wrong?

This feature did not land in 18.0 and won't in any 18.0.x as features only land in minor/major releases.
Also the PR you're pointing at is only a partial implementation, with follow-up PRs comming. (ex this one)
It's more likely to land in the upcomming minor (18.1).

This was driving me crazy! I upgraded to 19 and still had the problem. It's in the docs as of 18-something. Says it's in @angular/core, but I don't see it.
https://angular.dev/api/core/@let
